# Bind JSON with no root to table

Tags: json, xml, sapui5, xmltable

I have JSON data in this form:

```
[
  {
    "var1": 1,
    "var2": "test"
  },
  {
    "var1": 2,
    "var2": "something"
  }
]
```

Is it possible to bind this to a table or does the JSON need a root element? I can get 1 record to work if I change the url to /posts/1 but it cant handle multiple records.

```
var postsModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
postsModel.loadData('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
var mytab = this.byId('myTable');
mytab.setModel(postsModel);

<Page title="Settings Page">
        <content>
            <VBox>
                <Button press="getInvoices" text="Invoice getter" />
                <Table id="myTable" >
                    <columns>
                        <Column><header><Label text="userid"/></header></Column>
                        <Column><header><Label text="id"/></header></Column>
                        <Column><header><Label text="title"/></header></Column>
                        <Column><header><Label text="body"/></header></Column>
                    </columns>
                    <items>
                        <ColumnListItem>
                            <cells>
                                <Text text="{userId}" />
                                <Text text="{id}" />
                                <Text text="{title}" />
                                <Text text="{body}" />
                            </cells>
                        </ColumnListItem>
                    </items>
                </Table>
            </VBox>
        </content>
    </Page>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just adding items properties with a / should work. Like this.

```
<Table id="myTable" items="{/}">
```

https://jsbin.com/caximom/2/edit?html,output